# How do I organize my git repos when having multiple applications?

Tags: git, version-control

I have a system composed of several components that I'd like to have under source control and I'd like to know the pros/cons of different aproaches I might take.

This is the situation

- a component that comunicates with the backend
- the db creation scripts (tables, views, functions, stored procedures)
- three different front-ends (web pages)

The easiest thing would be to keep everything under the same repo (most common scenario is that I have to modify them all if, for example, I have to add a field to a table).

I don't find many advantages to keep everything in different repos, but I've seen a couple of applications organized that way, so I guess I must be missing something...

Answer (score 1):

The only advantage I am aware of for having multiple repositories for tightly coupled projects is if you expect them to be used independently and believe that cloning everything will be expensive if you have a single repository. Some people will claim that having independent histories is useful, but I've never found that to be useful after doing it for a while. I have found it to cause problems when you try to do `git bisect`-style debugging across multiple repositories.

If you go with multiple repositories for the above reason but must still frequently work with them together, then I'd recommend creating a super-repository that has all the others as submodules. That way, you can at least have snapshots in the history of the super-repository when each of the parts was consistent with the others.

If the common case is that the projects are used and modified together, then **they should be in one repository**. Many of the large tech companies I have worked at keep almost all of their code in one giant repository or a few large repositories.

Comment: thanks, great answer, I was wondering if the 'single repository approach' might be problematic when setting up a ci/cd pipeline, as you would end up building and delivering every app no matter if it was modified or not...

Comment: @opensas, I do not think so, because you should be able to configure the ci/cd tools to build and run the correct app depending on the pipeline.